# How to generate PDF with style and upload it to Server (Jquery)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, pdf

I am trying to generate a pdf file upload it to the server and NOT downloading it directly (local).

So i tried JsPdf, but the problem with Jspdf is that it doesnt save my stylesheet.

Then i tried Html2Pdf (this also works with my stylesheet) but i am not able to send the data to the "upload.php" file. I cant find the output syntax for html2pdf.

JS:

```
$("#printer").on("click",function(e){

var element = document.getElementById('qrcode');

html2pdf().from(element).toPdf().outputPdf().then(function(pdf) {
    //Convert to base 64


        var data = new FormData();
        data.append("data" , pdf);
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open( 'post', 'upload.php', true ); //Post to php Script to save to server
        xhr.send(data);


        })

});
```

My Pdf File on the Server is empty. And i dont know why.

upload.php:

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST['data'])){
    $data = $_POST['data'];
    $fname = "test.pdf"; // name the file
    $file = fopen("uploads/" .$fname, 'w'); // open the file path
    fwrite($file, $data); //save data
    fclose($file);
} else {
    echo "No Data Sent";
}
?>
```

I would really appreciate any help.

Just need to save the generated PDF file on my Server.

Comment: What did you get in error in network tab?

Comment: @Jaymin i dont get any Error. The uploaded PDF on my Server is currupted. When i open the PDF on my Server i get an error which says that the file is corrupted, so i am assuming that i cant filter the right data which i am sending to my php file.

Comment: Can u just output the pdf with some static test data nd check instead?

Comment: Even with static data it doesnt work. I tried it just now.

Comment: You are following same steps like here?
https://github.com/eKoopmans/html2pdf.js

Comment: Yes. I can save it localy on my computer as mentioned. But i am not able to send it to the php file and save it on the server.

Comment: @Jaymin I updated my Code. Now i can open my pdf on the server. But the file is empty and nothing is saved inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone has the same problem. I found the solution.

JS

```
$("#printer").on("click",function(e){

var element = document.getElementById('qrcode');

var opt = {

  image:        { type: 'jpeg', quality: 0.98 },
  html2canvas:  { scale: 3 },
  jsPDF:        { unit: 'cm', format: 'letter', orientation: 'landscape' }
};

html2pdf().from(element).set(opt).toPdf().output('datauristring').then(function (pdfAsString) {
    // The PDF has been converted to a Data URI string and passed to this function.
    // Use pdfAsString however you like (send as email, etc)!

var arr = pdfAsString.split(',');
pdfAsString= arr[1];    

        var data = new FormData();
        data.append("data" , pdfAsString);
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open( 'post', 'upload.php', true ); //Post the Data URI to php Script to save to server
        xhr.send(data);

        })

e.preventDefault();  //stop the browser from following
    window.location.href = 'uploads/file.pdf';

});
```

upload.php

```
<?php
$data = $_POST['data'];
$b64 = $data;

# Decode the Base64 string, making sure that it contains only valid characters
$bin = base64_decode($b64, true);

# Perform a basic validation to make sure that the result is a valid PDF file
# Be aware! The magic number (file signature) is not 100% reliable solution to validate PDF files
# Moreover, if you get Base64 from an untrusted source, you must sanitize the PDF contents
if (strpos($bin, '%PDF') !== 0) {
  throw new Exception('Missing the PDF file signature');
}

# Write the PDF contents to a local file
file_put_contents('uploads/file.pdf', $bin);
?>
```

Comment: this is not working for me